# cURL + PHP: Submitting a form with duplicate forms of the same form names

Tags: php, forms, curl, submit

I am trying to POST to a page that has two forms with duplicate name elements.  The problem is that one form gets the password value and the other form gets the login value. (I can see this by printing out curl_exec($ch);)  I will include my code for the target URL and the formdata.  How do I fix this?

```
// my target url and form data
$target = "http://www.example.com/login";
$formdata = "id=$login&password=$password&Submit=Log In";
```

Forms:

```
<form id="login" name="login" method="post" action="login">

            <label for="id">LOGIN ID</label>  <input type="text" value="" name="id" maxlength="50" size="30"><br>
            <label for="password">Password ID</label>  <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="12" size="30">
            <div align="center"><button class="siteSprite signInSm" value="Log In" name="Submit" type="submit"></button></div>
</form>


<form section="login" id="loginform" name="loginform" action="http://www.example.com/login" method="post">
<input type="text" size="20" value=" Log-in" onfocus="this.value=''" name="id"></td>
<input type="password" value="Password" maxlength="15" size="12" onfocus="this.value=''" name="password">
<input type="submit" class="siteSprite signInSm" value="Sign-In">
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a way to say I want to submit to the second form value?  Like &name[1]=UserNameHere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do something to indicate which of the two forms got submitted. You can either submit a field with the same name but different values in each one, or use the submit button:

```
<form ...>
    <input type="hidden" name="whichform" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="form 1" />
</form>

<form ...>
    <input type="hidden" name="whichform" value="2" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="form 2" />
</form>
```

and then

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (($_POST['Submit'] == 'form 1') || ($_POST['whichform'] == '1')) {
        .... handle form #1 ....
    }
    if (($_POST['Submit'] == 'form 2') || ($_POST['whichform'] == '2')) {
        .... handle form #1 ....
    }
```

using either method works the same, just pick the one that makes most sense/is easiest and go from there.

Comment: may want to fix the numbers on your 2nd form. :)

Comment: right. thanks. I really need to wake up... 11:30am and still not conscious, while at work. not good.

Comment: Try 9:30 AM and no coffee. ;)

Answer (score 1):

<s>`$formdata = "id=$login&password=$password&Submit=Sign-In";` might do the trick; note the fact that the second form has a submit button with a value, and the first form has a `<button>` which won't send a value (or, maybe, sends a different value via script or something)</s>

I just noticed that the submit button doesn't have a name; try passing it with NO submit parameter, i.e.:

```
$formdata = "id=$login&password=$password
```